# Password Creation validation in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I create password validation with case sensitivity and special characters detection for password detection in react native?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex for a password check of uppercase lower case number and special characters

```
function checkPassword(str)
{
    var re =  /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
    return re.test(str);
}
```